# Como forzar a que un texto no sea tomado como hipervínculo por los servicios de correo electrónico?

Tags: html, email, gmail, outlook

Sucede que estoy maquetando un mail en html4, pero al pasar un texto que lleva un **.pe** al final, los servicios de correo electrónico lo tomas como un link de redirección.

Answer (score 0):

En [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625880/prevent-urls-from-appearing-as-links-in-mail-clients) se resuelve esta inquietud. Se sugiere usar etiquetas HTML vacías entre partes de la URL, o usar caracteres Unicode invisibles.

`sitio.pe` se representaría como `sitio.<span></span>pe` o `sitio.&#8203;pe`.